# How to update schema in a dockerized postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml` config to run a dockerized postgres instance:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest

    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Here in `db_scripts` I have a set of initial sql files that create tables on first start. Then when I stop and start docker instance, these scripts are not applied anymore which is fine.

Though, from time to time I need to update schema - change columns format, add tables, add or remove columns.

What's the preferred way to run schema updates and migrations when I run it inside docker?

The most obvious way to me is to just start the instance and execute sql changes on a running instance, though it's more a manual process.

Is there a recommended way of automating this process?

Comment: Generally I have seen schema update is made part of application which is using the DB and there are many opensource tools to do that job for e.g. in Java we have Liquibase of Flyway.

Comment: You'd do this the exact same way you'd do it if the database wasn't in Docker.  Most higher-level database libraries have some sort of migrations system and I'd use that.

Comment: Are you using some kind of ORM? Like ``sqlalchemy`` or ``Django ORM``?